# How to receive updates from server without refreshing webpage

Tags: php, ajax, html

What's the best way to constantly receive updates for few `<div>`'s without refreshing web page?
Is the Server sent events best option?

Comment: btw: i need only one-way communication, server to browser. Not browser  to server by any chance and to be more specific i only need to load images in 6 divs.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets (push technology) is your answer. Repeated ajax calls will result in a lot of unnecessary requests. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883540/http-server-to-client-push-technologies-standards-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to refresh the contents of a DIV once in a while without reloading the entire page, I highly recommend just using a JavaScript framework called JQuery. It has very easy-to-write code, and it's very simple to set a timer and reload a div at a certain interval - or on a click.

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

All you need to do is include the script tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your document, and JavaScript can then use all sorts of AJAX shorthand and DIV loading code, such as `$("#divID").load("http://somesite.com/new/content/for/div");`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get a couple updates, old school ajax short polling is probably fine.  If you need to maintain a constant connection that updates at random intervals, you'll need a more robust option, to which there's a lot.

socket.io, nodejs, faye, comet, websockets, etc.  Depends on the compatibility level you want with browsers and your exact needs.

EDIT: Just to update a couple DIVs you're probably fine just doing a few AJAX requests.

Comment: Yes, I need to update images on 6 divs. I have query in php which loads few paths to images and i just have to put them on those 6 divs already on page

Answer (score 0):

Server Sent Events are not supported in all browsers.

Maybe take a look at [websockets](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091222/)